# Algorithm for removing a symbol and generating permutations

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have the following char array "AbA" and I want to generate a set of char arrays which represents all possible combinations of removing the char='A' from the initial char array ,so the result will be a set containing "bA","Ab","b" another example is  "AbAbA",then the result will be "bAbA" ,"AbbA" ,"AbAb","bbA" and so on the last element will be bb ( without 3 A's) .How can I create such an algorithm ,what should be the idea?

Comment: Thanks for the specification, whats your question?

Comment: My questions is any ideas how to create such an algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), as well as all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons you will get negative votes.

Comment: I'd use a `std::set`, and put all the suitable permutations in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a backtrack algorithm and using a for loop remove each appearance of the pattern character in the original string and check if the found string has been created before, if not print it and run the backtrack algorithm on the string with the found character omitted from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

set <string> combinations;

inline void back_track_character_remover (string orig, char pat){

    for (int i=0 ; i<orig.size()-1 ; i++){
        if (orig[i]==pat){ // find each appearance of pattern on original string
            int t = combinations.size();
            string new_orig = orig.substr(0,i)+orig.substr(i+1,orig.size()-i-1); // create new string with the found pattern omitted
            combinations.insert(new_orig);
            if (combinations.size()!=t){ // check if adding the new string makes a new permutation
                cout << new_orig << endl; // print new combination 
                back_track_character_remover(new_orig,pat); // checl new string to find other appearances of pattern
            }
        }
    }
    // for easier use of for loop check last element separately
    int t = combinations.size();
    if (orig[orig.size()-1]==pat){
        string new_orig = orig.substr(0,orig.size()-1);
        combinations.insert(new_orig);
        if (combinations.size()!=t){
            cout << new_orig << endl;
            back_track_character_remover(new_orig,pat);
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    string original;
    char pattern;
    cin >> original >> pattern;
    combinations.empty();
    cout << original << endl;
    back_track_character_remover(original,pattern);

}
```